# Eject CD using Java

Tags: java, disk

Is there any simple way to eject the D drive in Windows 7 using Java? I don't particularly care about cross-platform compatibility at the moment. I've done some research and`Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` has shown up most... but I have no idea what to put as the string parameter, I've tried a few things but it just throws up on me!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the vbscript code to eject the cd as an argument in the `exec()` function.