# How to open cd drive java

Tags: java

Is there a code, I can use that will (once I run it), physically open the cd/dvd drive? I know this is possible in some other languages, but is it possible in Java? Please point me in the correct direction. Thank you

Comment: [previously][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813876/eject-cd-using-java

Comment: Any particular platform? (The answer's generally "no, but you can make Java execute [appropriate command for ejecting drive on platform X]").

Comment: @JohnFlatness I'm looking for a solution on the windows platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java provides no way to interact with a cd drive. 
One easy way on the Windows plateform is to call a VBS script.

Few links which might help you:

[Example 1](http://forums.devarticles.com/java-development-38/how-to-open-the-cd-drive-with-java-programming-8207.html)

[Example 2](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2009/03/java-open-cd-tray-in-windows-xp.html)

[Example 3](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/221-how-open-close-computers-cd-dvd-drive.html)

Answer (score 2):

The code to open a CD drive can be even simpler than meain's answer.
The .exe file does not need to be copied. It can be run from a command line inside the program :

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nircmd cdrom open d:");`

It should execute and find the `nircmd.exe` file automatically in the system bin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ninrcmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). It an exe file and has a built in function to open the CD drive.

```
nircmd.exe cdrom open j:
```

and to close it

```
nircmd.exe cdrom close j:
```

---

To use it add the exe into your program and use this code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.getClass().getResource("nircmd.exe cdrom open j").getPath());
```