# What is the best way to access hardware such as DVD drive using java script?

Tags: javascript

Functions like detection of inserted media, dvd tray is open or not. Currently, I'm using a native assembly exposed via activex.

Comment: From a browser? You can't.

Comment: @Matt Of course you can; you can use a windows ActiveX as Prince said.

Comment: @Marco: He said he's already using ActiveX. He wants a x-browser way.

Comment: @Matt I know, but what Prince was saying was for windows. It is now what the OP asked but I was replying to you.

Comment: Just to confirm: should this be tagged `node.js`? Are you using ActiveX within Node.js, or from a browser?

Comment: Since you've tagged this [tag:node.js], are you asking about the DVD tray of your server machine?

Comment: @apsillers I'm accessing from a browser.

Comment: @bergi no in my client machines tray. I was looking for possible ways to avoid activex usage. Won't I be able to use node.js in this regard?

Comment: @PrinceAshitaka Definitely not, unless you are running Node on the machine whose DVD drive you want to access. Thus, you could either ask every user to install and run a private Node.js instance (in which case you're not in the browser anymore, you're running a totally new program) or you can have the browser talk to a Node.js server (which could read its own DVD drive, but not the DVD of every client that connects to it).

Comment: @apsillers thanks for the clear clarification. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless you use ActiveX on windows for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MSWebDVD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which should give you access to DVD controls.

Comment: thanks for the link. I was looking for a solution which doesn't involve ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

Not javascript but c# or java would do..[How to open cd drive java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829113/how-to-open-cd-drive-java)

[Java](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/221-java-program-open-close-computer-cd-dvd-drive.html)

[c#](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2013/05/how-to-eject-and-close-cddvd-drive-in-c.html)